# Why doesn't this operation reveal the voter's message?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, zero-knowledge-proofs, voting

I am working my way through [this paper](http://www.win.tue.nl/~berry/papers/euro97.pdf). I am trying to figure out the OR zero knowledge proof in figure 2. The prover is verifying that she has correctly voted, and that her input satisfies
$$\log_gx=\log_h{(y/m_0)} \wedge \log_gx=\log_h{(y/m_1)}$$
The authors' protocol for this makes sense except for one thing. After the prover receives the challenge $c$, she sets $d_2 \leftarrow c - d_1$ if her vote is 1, or $d_1 \leftarrow c - d_1$ if her vote is -1. Because $c \in_R \mathbb{Z}$ and the previously set $d$ is also $\in_R \mathbb{Z}$, the new $d$ could be negative.

However, in the final step, the verifier needs to compute two values to the power of each $d$. This means the prover can't simply send $d \mod p$, and must send $d$ even if it is negative. But the other $d$ value will never be negative.

Doesn't this mean that verifier can learn the prover's vote? If $d_2$ is negative then she voted 1, or if $d_1$ is negative then she voted -1.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, it's quite simple actually.

The $d$ values (and $r$ values) are all exponents and chosen from $\mathbb{Z}_q$. Thus all calculations on them directly take place in $\mathbb{Z}_q$. Applying mod $q$ (not mod $p$) to all of my calculations on $d$ and $r$ fixed any problems with calculations.